# How to Access values from dictionary in Javascript

Tags: javascript, django, ajax

I am try to fetch my item_id field from model.py in django in  query set form that below

```
<QuerySet [<Item: Shoulder Bag Boys Shoulder Bag (Yellow )>,
<Item: Sweeter Cotton Sweeter>,
<Item: Shirt Full Sleeves Shirt>, <Item: Jacket Jackson Jacket>, 
<Item: Yellow Shoes Leopard Shoes>, 
<Item: Bag Mini Cary Bag>, <Item: Coat Overcoat (Gray)>,
<Item: TOWEL Pure Pineapple>,
<Item: Coat Pure Pineapple>, <Item: TOWEL Pure Pineapple (White)>]>
```

Here is my JS Code

```
 $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/shopsorting/' + selected_value,
            // data: formData,
            encode: true
        })
        .done(function(data) {
            items = JSON.parse(data)
            console.log(items)
            for (var item in items) {
                console.log(item['product_id'])
            };
```

But it print in console

```
`(index):765
{items: "<QuerySet [<Item: TOWEL Pure Pineapple>, <Item: Ba…s Leopard Shoes>, <Item: Jacket Jackson 
Jacket>]>"}

(index):767 undefined`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to convert data into a string before receiving it:

```
x = JSON.stringify(data); 
items = JSON.parse(x);
```

Don't forget the **';'**

```
    $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '\/shopsorting\/' + selected_value,
            // data: formData,
            encode: true,
            success: function(data) {
                x = JSON.stringify(data);
                items = JSON.parse(x);
                console.log(items);
                for (var item in items) {
                    console.log(item['product_id'])
                };
}});
```

Comment: my APi views.py from where the data is sent  `def SortShop(request,shortby):
                                                                         items = Item.objects.order_by(shortby)
                                                                         send = {'items':items}
                                                                         data = json.dumps(send,default=str)
                                                                         return HttpResponse(data)`

Comment: I mean by my answer JS code: function(data). However it would be better if you change your query to have a dict, and then do a JsonResponse instead of HttpResponse

Comment: Let me know if you have any other issue